# can not use many imshows() in Matlab

Tags: matlab, imshow

I can't use multiple `imshow()` in one project and my code can only see the last `imshow()`.

```
n=10;
a = magic(n);
b=a/(n^2);
imshow(a)
imshow(b)
```

What's my problem ?

Answer (score 2):

You should `imshow` them on separate figures or sub-figures:

Use

```
figure;imshow(a);
figure;imshow(b);
```

or

```
figure;
subplot(1,2,1);imshow(a);
subplot(1,2,2);imshow(b);
```